# Webflux and R2dbc-mysql demo, run failed

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor, r2dbc, r2dbc-mysql

When I first tried to use webflux and r2dbc-mysql, I encountered a strange problem.This is my project structure diagram:
[image]

**package com.example.r2dbcdemo.controller**;

```
package com.example.r2dbcdemo.controller;

import com.example.r2dbcdemo.entity.User;
import com.example.r2dbcdemo.repo.UserRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;

@RestController
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @GetMapping(path = "/getAllUsers")
    public Flux<User> getAllUsers() {
        Flux<User> users = userRepository.findAll();
        return users;
    }

}
```

**com/example/r2dbcdemo/entity**

```
package com.example.r2dbcdemo.entity;

import lombok.Data;
import org.springframework.data.relational.core.mapping.Table;

@Data
@Table("user")
public class User {
    private Long id;
    private String name;

}
```

**com/example/r2dbcdemo/repo**

```
package com.example.r2dbcdemo.repo;

import com.example.r2dbcdemo.entity.User;
import org.springframework.data.repository.reactive.ReactiveCrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends ReactiveCrudRepository<User, Long> {
}
```

**And the application.yml**

```
spring:
    r2dbc:
        url: r2dbc:mysql://localhost:3306/my_blog_db?useSSL=false
        username:root
        password:root
```

This is the main funcation:

```
package com.example.r2dbcdemo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.r2dbc.R2dbcAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.config.EnableWebFlux;

@SpringBootApplication(exclude = R2dbcAutoConfiguration.class, scanBasePackages = {"com.example.r2dbcdemo"})
public class R2dbcDemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(R2dbcDemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

This is the first time for me to use webflux and r2bdc. I thought this demo could run normally, but the following error was thrown during startup. This operation result has troubled me for a long time, please help me!

> 2023-06-12T22:49:11.533+08:00 ERROR 27576 --- [           main]
> o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   :
>
> *************************** APPLICATION FAILED TO START
>
> ---
>
> Description:
>
> Field userRepository in
> com.example.r2dbcdemo.controller.UserController required a bean of
> type 'com.example.r2dbcdemo.repo.UserRepository' that could not be
> found.
>
> The injection point has the following annotations:
>
> - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)
>
> Action:
>
> Consider defining a bean of type
> 'com.example.r2dbcdemo.repo.UserRepository' in your configuration.
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

ps:
jdk17,springboot3.1.0,r2dbc-mysql:0.8.2.RELEASE,webflux:3.1.0.pom

Comment: `exclude = R2dbcAutoConfiguration.class` why have you removed the R2dbcAutoConfiguration? this is exactly what sets up your repos

Comment: I didn't add this at first, but it would report an exception like this.to fix it, so I added this, which then led to the above problem

Comment: ---------------------------------
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
---------------------------------

*Description*:

Failed to configure a ConnectionFactory: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded database could be configured.

*Reason*: Failed to determine a suitable R2DBC Connection URL


*Action*:

Consider the following:
 If you want an embedded database (H2), please put it on the classpath.
 If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to activate it (no profiles are currently active).

Comment: Read that error message, its crystal clear